# Is it possible to filter content  displayed by the  Views module using a regular expression?

Tags: views

Is there a way to filter content displayed by Views 3 using a regular expression?

I have a large list (10K items) of content of a custom type on my site and I want to create preset views for my users.  The default views filter is not selective enough.  I need to select with a regular expression such as /M [0-9][0-9]?[0-9]?/ in one of the fields.

Is this possible in some other way, not using a regular expression?

I'm using Drupal 7.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set up a `Contextual Filter` (previously know as `Arguments` in D6), they're hiding under the "Advanced" menu of you view. There you can put some PHP code to return a list of arguments.

Here is an example from one of my views, my PHP code return ID for a field regarding the roles of a user, it returns a string separated by "+" like `1+2+3` which is the separator for "OR" so I can select various node which have these values in this field.
[image: PHP code to provide default value]

This is the configuration to provide multiple arguments.
[image: Multiple arguments configuration]

Comment: Where can I get the background to understand this answer?  I don't know where to plug in my RegEx or my field name.  I'm not skilled enough with PHP under Drupal to make sense of this answer.  Where do I go to get the info?